# Cast a column to a different type in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery, m

I have the following query to combined two fields of different types:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"New Column", "Calculated Column", each [Age] + [#"New-Name"])
```

`Age` is a number, and `New-Name` is a text field. However, I would like to cast the `Age` to a text field to concatenate the two fields together. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"New Column", "Calculated Column", each  Text.From([Age]) & [#"New-Name"])
```

Text.From to cast as text

& to concatenate

Comment: is string concatenation done with `&` and not `+` in M?

Comment: Exactly. `+` can give you unexpected results